# Netty - Http , web browser ,web page didn't reveive anything

Tags: netty

I have some problems during writing Netty http server that sends/receives  data,
And I would very appreciate anybody help or explanation.

My client (html) code like this:

>

```
        $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url : "http://localhost:9999/MyTest/",
          data : {"servicename":"aptest","querymsg":{"wsid":"111" ,"telid":"1111","role":"1"}}, 
          dataType:"json",
          timeout:100000,
          beforeSend: function(xhr) { //add header data
              },
          success: function(rs) {
              alert("[success]"  + rs);
             },
           complete:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){
              if(XMLHttpRequest.readyState=="4"){
                  alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
              }
              },  
     error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
              alert("error:"+textStatus);
          }       

        });
```

Server side code :

> 

```
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), 
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
            );


    HttpServerPipelineFactory pipeline = new HttpServerPipelineFactory();
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(pipeline);
    serverChannel = bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(Port));
```

HttpRequestServerHandler:

> Blockquote

```
   HttpResponse res = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK);
    res.setContent(
            ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(
                    "Test", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    setContentLength(res, res.getContent().readableBytes());        
    res.setChunked(true);
    res.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");


    // Send the response and close the connection if necessary.
    ChannelFuture f = ctx.getChannel().write(res);
```

Comment: no error ,but in browser side , show alert that content is [success]null

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set your HttpRequest to be chunked. When doing so its content becomes empy. This is stated also in the javadocs, see [1].

If you really want to use a chunked response you will need to first write a HttpResponse which is marked as chunked and then write the content of it via HttpChunk. See [2].

[1] http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpMessage.html

[2] http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpChunk.html